# Three.js - SSAO defect transparent area

Tags: three.js, webgl, post-processing, ssao

I've been trying to add SSAO into my game, per this [SSAO EXAMPLE](http://www.mrdoob.com/projects/htmleditor/#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)

Unfortunately, my transparent trees now defected:
[image]

Please advise on how to fix it.

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a defect, during the depth-Path, which you need to pass to the SSAO shader further on, transparency is not taken into account, thus your leave-defining planes get detected as planar geometry and get the appropriate outline. 
Concerning a solution, I cannot really help you. What you can do is hide all the transparent stuff before rendering the depth pass but then, the AO-pass gets multiplied over it, so you just trade in a visual problem against another one. To really solve this, i think you need an additional Three.MaskPass, see here:

[Rendering multiple scenes, with only 1 using SSAO [Three.js]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275986/rendering-multiple-scenes-with-only-1-using-ssao-three-js)

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can I hide the transparent stuff before rendering the depth pass?

Comment: object/mesh.visible = false but as i said, this will only "shift" the real problem...

Comment: Well, it didn't solved my Issue. if you have any other suggestion - please let me know.

Comment: well, as I said above, this will only shift the problem and you will need some kind of renderMask but i am not sure about how to achieve this. See the link i gave in my first answer. Sorry, cannot help any further

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the texture into the normal/depth fragment shader and discard any fragments with an alpha < 0.5